# How to get data from two tables using web api

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I want to get data from two tables using web api, but I'm receiving an error.

Here is my code:

```
public List<tblEmpTask> GettblEmpTasks()
        {
var q = (from n in db.tblEmpTasks
                     join c in db.tblEmployees on n.intEmpCode equals c.intEmpCode

                     select new
                     {
                         n.strTaskName,
                         n.dtStart,
                         c.strEmployeeName,

                     }).ToList();
            return q;
}
```

Here is the error that I'm receiving:

```
  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

and please note that I am using web api. Looking forward to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

when selecting an anonymous the function should return `List<object>`
 *or instead*
use a type to return value such as-

```
    class myType{
            string TaskName,     //assuming type as string
            string dtStart,     //assuming type as string
            string EmployeeName //assuming type as string
    }
```

and in LinQ query something like -

```
select new myType{ TaskName=n.strTaskName, dtStart=n.dtStart, EmployeeName=c.strEmployeeName}
```

and return as `List<myType>`

Comment: `var q = (from n in db.tblEmpTasks
                     join c in db.tblEmployees on n.intEmpCode equals c.intEmpCode

                     select new tblEmpTask
                     {
                        strTaskName= n.strTaskName
                        

                     }).ToList();
            return q;` Here is my new code, but still getting same error

Comment: intEmpCode  of db.tblEmpTasks should have same type as of intEmpCode of tblEmployees